# Next Page / Previous Page not working for Django pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination

I was hoping someone could help me with a pagination question.

I am trying to use Django pagination following the information on this page (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/). Whilst I have successfully displayed the correct number of items on the first page and the last page works, the next and previous pages keep taking me to the first page.

I think the issue may revolve around the ‘request’ element and I’m not sure if I am picking up an incorrect version. The example states:-

```
def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

The command:

```
page = request.GET.get(‘page’)
```

returns “AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'GET'”

By replacing this code with:

```
page = request.args.get('page', type=int)
```

the code successfully renders the first (and last) page but next and previous do not work.

As background I built my system on the Flask megatutorial but I have been unable to use that pagination, I understand because I haven’t used the Flask SQL Alchemy for creating and updating databases. My routes file has

```
from flask import request
```

Should I replace this with another utility's “request” and if so, which?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Are you using Flask or Django? You can't mix them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was in a missing () within the HTML file:-

```
    <a href="?page={{ userlist.next_page_number }}">  next</a>
```

listed within the example should have been:

```
    <a href="?page={{ userlist.next_page_number() }}">  next</a>
```